# Redis - Total Keys in Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I want to check total number of keys in Redis Cluster.

Is there any direct command available to get this or I have to check with INFO command from each instance / node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way.

You can do the following with the cli though:

```
redis-cli --cluster call one-cluster-node-ip-address:the-port DBSIZE
```

And then sum the results.

Alternatively, there's [RedisGears](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears) with which you can do the following to get the same result:

```
redis> RG.PYEXECUTE "GB().count().run()"
```